# What scala or java library can be used to crawl +10M pages daily from 1000 domains in the most efficient way

Tags: performance, scala, web-crawler, spray

I am making web crawler. I already tried async http client like the one from scala tutorial [scaling-out-with-scala-and-akka](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling-out-with-scala-and-akka) and [spray](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-M8/spray-can/http-client/request-level/#requestlevelapi) but i can't manage to make it work. For now performance is not the most important part for me, but later on i would like to easy improve req/s ratio without changing library.

Library should be able to operate on http headers and should not have performance issues with dns resolving. What library should be the best for the task?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "can't manage to make it work"? Also, it's unlikely that the library is going to be the bottleneck here—especially since most of the good ones for Scala are DSLs for `async-http-client`.

Answer (score 5):

Spray should be sufficient for that. Even with this very simple code on a 16mbit connection I can search through around 8 pages per second, i.e. 700,000 pages per day.
It fetches all the links on the main page of wikipedia, loads all those pages and then fetches all the links on those pages.
The problem is that wikipedia's server probably limits the traffic per client, so if I access several sites at once I should get much more speed.
It uses parallel collections to speed it up and avoid delay through dns resolving. But if you write this properly with actors and or futures, using a library like spray I'm guessing it would be faster.

```
import io.Source

def time[T](f: => T): T = {
  val start = System.nanoTime
  val r = f
  val end = System.nanoTime
  val time = (end - start)/1e6
  println("time = " + time +"ms")
  r
}

val domain = "https://en.wikipedia.org"
val startPage = "/wiki/Main_Page"
val linkRegex = """\"/wiki/[a-zA-Z\-_]+\"""".r


def getLinks(html: String): Set[String] =
  linkRegex.findAllMatchIn(html).map(_.toString.replace("\"", "")).toSet

def getHttp(url: String) = {
  val in = Source.fromURL(domain + url, "utf8")
  val response = in.getLines.mkString
  in.close()
  response
}

val links = getLinks(getHttp(startPage))
links.foreach(println)
println(links.size)

val allLinks = time(links.par.flatMap(link => getLinks(getHttp(link))))
println(allLinks.size)
```